# cakephp 2.0 smtp email

Tags: php, smtp, cakephp-2.0, starttls

I am trying to send a email message using CakePhp 2.0. in my controller i use this code (i know it's fine, i took it from [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html)) :

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$email = new CakeEmail("myConfig");
$email->from(array('from@example.com' => 'From Example'));
$email->to($to);
$email->subject($msgtitle);
$ok = $email->send($content);
```

and in `app/config/email.php` i have this config :

```
<?php
class EmailConfig {
    public $myConfig = array(
        'host' => 'mail.myServer.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'username' => 'mYaccount',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
}
?>
```

the problem is  the server answers with :

```
SMTP Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
```

the account name is correct, as is the password. The config works when loading it up in thunderbird, the connection to the smtp server is set up as :

server name : mail.myServer.com
port : 587
connection security :  STARTTLS
authentication : normal password
user name : mYaccount

Comment: If you want to see some CakePHP code that sends SMTP commands, check out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294751/using-gmails-outgoing-smtp-from-php-using-tls

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain your SMTP supports tls? Try sending the ehlo command:

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 25
ehlo testing
```

You should see something like:

```
250-STARTTLS
```

in the list.

If you see it, then it is most likely not enabled. You will need to enable it. If you do not see it, you will need to add it.

Comment: ok, i DO see it in the list, how do i check if it's enabled? (keep in mind that it IS working using a email client and STARTTLS is what the email client is reporting to be using)

Comment: Then you should be able to make the host `ssl://mail.myServer.com` and it should connect. If it does not, you may need to validate you are using the correct username and password. Did you try the username as an email address? `username@myServer.com`

Answer (score 2):

```
public $smtp = array(
        .................,
        'tls'   =>  true
    );
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working for me over GoDaddy server using CakePHP SMTP Email:

Email.php file inside config folder - CakePHP 2.4 MVC version:

```
    // for Live Server GoDaddy.com domain
    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtpout.asia.secureserver.net', <-- important
        'port' => 465, <-- important
        #'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'no-reply@godaddy-domain.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        #'tls' => false,
        #'log' => false,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```

And here is the controller file code below:

```
    // Controller Code to Send Actual Email
    // email configuration
    $Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
    $Email->from(array('no-reply@godaddy-domain.com' => 'App Name'))
        ->sender('no-reply@godaddy-domain.com', 'App Name')
        ->to(array($email))
        ->bcc(array('xyz@xyz.com'))
        ->subject('Test Email from GoDaddy')
        ->emailFormat('both')
        ->send($hash.'<br><strong>My</strong> message 45 قبل الميلاد، مما يجعله أكثر من');
```

Hope it helps !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the CakePHP Cookbook:

> You can configure SSL SMTP servers, like GMail. To do so, put the 'ssl://' at prefix in the host and configure the port value accordingly. Example:
>
> ```
> class EmailConfig {
> public $gmail = array(
>     'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
> (...)
> ```

Comment: if i do that, i just get `Unable to connect to SMTP server.`

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:

```
 <?php
class EmailConfig {
    public $myConfig = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://mail.myServer.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'mYaccount',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your

> php_openssl.dll

extension is running.

You can check it on the`php.ini` file.

If you are using XAMPP php.ini should be on `C:\xampp\php`

```
   php.ini:

;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```