# Cannot connect to gmail SMTP Server

Tags: php, cakephp, smtp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.0. I am trying to send mail using cakephp through gmail SMTP Server. I am trying to do it from my localhost so I don't have ssl. This is the configuration I've done in app.php:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'gmail'=>[
        'className'=>'Smtp',
        'host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port'=>587,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'username'=>'myemail@gmail.com',
        'password'=>'mypassword',
        'tls' => true,
    ]
]
```

This is where I've created my email profile :

```
'Email' => [
    'gmail' => [
        'transport' => 'gmail',
        'from' => 'myemail@gmail.com'
    ]
],
```

This is the code from my custom mailer class :

```
    $mail
        ->to($email)
        ->profile('gmail')
        ->subject($this->subject)
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->template('welcome')
        ->viewVars([
            $name=>$name,
            $code=>$code
        ]);
```

I've already allowed access to less secure apps in my gmail account. This is the error cakephp is throwing :

> SMTP server did not accept the connection or trying to connect to non TLS SMTP server using TLS

Attaching a complete snapshot of the error :

[image]

Comment: Possible had been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341787/cakephp-2-0-smtp-email

Comment: hope that my previous answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/35263987/4098311

Comment: @HalayemAnis Thank you. Your previous answer is the reason I could reach to my answer below. :)

Comment: @Sourabh glad that i helped you .. you can always upvote my previous answer :)

Comment: @HalayemAnis already done. :)

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. Added these parameters in the transport config to bypass ssl authentication:

```
        'context' => [
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ]
        ]
```

Worked like a charm.