# How to send email from IIS PHP using gmail SMTP?

Tags: php, email

How can I use IIS6 PHP with gmail smtp. I am running windows 7.

My php.ini file has on the bottom

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = [username]
auth_password = [password]
sendmail_from = [username]@gmail.com
```

When I try it in php, I get the error:

**Warning**:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in **C:\Users\Me\Desktop\App\App\script\config\common.php** on line **60**

Right now, the server is on my home wifi network (router, modem).
However if I connect my server to my LTE phone data plan, then it works fine.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Maybe a firewall thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this particular circumstance, I suspect your LTE provider is firewalling port 25.

Gmail does have some alternative ways to send mail that might work. Take a look here and see if any of these scenarios will meet your needs.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: I tried with port 587 (TLS) and the response was `mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i93sm2004911iod.7 - gsmtp`

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow post for an example using TLS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294751/using-gmails-outgoing-smtp-from-php-using-tls